# Tree View MVC Not being populated properly

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

Im Trying to create a tree view menu, but it isnt working properly. There are 3 different stored procedures, 1st for families (parent), 2nd for categories(child), and 3rd for reports(grandchild). Families SP takes user id as paramters and seems to be working fine. Category SP takes userID and familyID and 3rd takes userID, FamilyID and CategoryID. When runnning the code it does display the families, and displays the 1 report name underneath. If I remove line of code that calls the stored procedure out of the foreach loop, it does return categories for 1 family, although it displays on all the families.

If I add a breakpoint on on the controller it will go through the loops and return the correct data, so I assume the issue is in the way it is being displayed .[Displayed data] On this screenshot is possible to see how the data is being displayed, being EPOS and RES being retuned from family SP and WebBooking which is a category

```
FAMILIES
¦
¦--CATEGORIES
   ¦
   ¦
   ¦---REPORT_NAME
```

Thank you In advance!

On the controller I'm calling each of the stored procedures, and if tested with a breakpoint all the data that should be returned is being returned properly. Perhaps a solution for my problem would be populate the view with the returned data from the controller, however I don't know how to do it?

**Controller**

```
       foreach (var cat in model.familiesReport = context.P_Mob_Get_ReportFamilies(user).ToList()) 
             {
                Console.WriteLine(cat.FamilyName);
                foreach (var name in model.CategoriesReport = context.P_Mob_Get_ReportCategories(user, cat.FamilyID).ToList())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name.Category);

                    foreach (var test in model.namesReport = context.P_Mob_Get_ReportNames(user, cat.FamilyID, name.CategoryID).ToList())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(test.ReportName);
                        
                    }
                    
                 }
```

I have got a View Model that has the 3 SP_Results (Complex types in EF). On the view I am going through every single Complex type and return the name for each one, (Family, Category, Name)

**View**

```
        <ul>
            @foreach (var family in Model.familiesReport)
            {
                <a href="#" class="menu_fam">@family.FamilyName</a>
            
                <ul class="">
                    @foreach (var cat in Model.CategoriesReport)
                    {
                        <li href="#" class=""><a class="menu_cat"> @cat.Category</a></li>
                    

                        <ul class="">
                            @foreach (var name in Model.namesReport)
                            {

                                <li href="#" class=""><a class="menu_name">   @name.ReportName</a></li>
                            }


                        </ul>
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        </ul>
```

Comment: You'll really need to narrow the issue down. Is it a stored procedure / data issue or is it a web rendering issue? You haven't actually stated the issue here. Please narrow the issue down and edit your question and state the issue. As is, this is too broad to assist with.

Comment: I have just edited the question. Apologies

Comment: It's still unclear. What do you expect to see? what are you getting? are families / cateogries / reports different levels on the tree? You need to analyse the data until instead of saying "seems to be working fine" you can say "definitely works as intended" I suggest you remove the linked picture and show a text representation of what you expect, and what you are seeing.

Comment: In your sample picture it would appear reports are not appearing when you expect them to. First confirm that a line is running in your view code to render the report line. If you can't see it on the page, right click the web page and press `inspect` and dig through the html and see if you can find your report element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution for this. Ive created a new model and instead of saving the results of the stored procedure in the complex types generated by EF saved them in this model. Each class in the model has a list where the data will be saved. as displayed bellow.
Model:

```
 public class FamilyResultResponse
{
    public List<Family> Families { get; set; }
    public List<Sites> SitesGet { get; set; }
}

public class Family
{

    public Nullable<int> FamilyID { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public List<FamilyResultCat> FamilyCat { get; set; }


}
public class FamilyResultCat
{
    public Nullable<int> familyid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Allowed { get; set; }

    public List<FamilyResulReportByCategory> FamilCatRep { get; set; }

}

public class FamilyResulReportByCategory
{

    public Nullable<int> ReportID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> categoryid { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }


}
```

Controller:
Iterate through the lists

```
        public ActionResult Index(Guid? userID\)
    {

        
        var model = new FamilyResultResponse();
        model.Families=new List<Family>();
        SPMenuModel modelSPMEnu = new SPMenuModel();
     


        foreach (var f in context.P_Mob_Get_ReportFamilies(userID).ToList())
        {
            var fam = new Family();
            fam.FamilyID = f.FamilyID;
            fam.FamilyName= f.FamilyName;
            fam.FamilyCat = new List<FamilyResultCat>();

            Console.WriteLine(f.FamilyName);
            foreach (var c in  context.P_Mob_Get_ReportCategories(userID, f.FamilyID).ToList())
            {
                var famcat = new FamilyResultCat();
                famcat.CategoryID = c.CategoryID;
                famcat.Category = c.Category;
                famcat.Allowed = c.Allowed;
                famcat.FamilCatRep= new List<FamilyResulReportByCategory>();

                Console.WriteLine(c.Category);
                foreach (var n in context.P_Mob_Get_ReportNames(userID, f.FamilyID, c.CategoryID).ToList())
                {
                    var famcatrep = new FamilyResulReportByCategory();
                    famcatrep.ReportID = n.ReportID;
                    famcatrep.ReportName = n.ReportName;
                    famcatrep.categoryid = n.categoryid;
                    Console.WriteLine(n.ReportName);
                    famcat.FamilCatRep.Add(famcatrep);
                }
                fam.FamilyCat.Add(famcat);
            }
            model.Families.Add(fam);

        }
      


        modelSPMEnu.familyResult = model;


        return View(model);
```

View

```
            @foreach (var fam in Model.Families)
        {
            <a href="#" class="menu_fam"> @fam.FamilyName</a>

            <ul class="">
                @foreach (var cat in fam.FamilyCat)

                {

                    <li href="#" class=""><a class="menu_cat"> @cat.Category </a></li>
                    foreach (var name in cat.FamilCatRep)
                    {
                        <ul class="">
                            <li class=""><a>@name.ReportName</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                }


            </ul>

        }
```